# Extract seaweed iodine from petroleum ether and cyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm working on iodine extraction from seaweed by using petroleum ether and cyclohexane. I have already observe the presence of iodine in the solution but I don't know how to extract the iodine in a solid form. I try to boil it but it does not work because there is no iodine left after the process. Hope to get the answer ASAP since I'm at nick of time
[image: Extraction using petroleum ether]

Comment: What is your goal. Do you want to quantitivly measure how much iodine is extracted? Or you just want to qualitivly show, that it is iodine?
One idea would be, tro transfer the iodide into a salt which can not evaporate.

Comment: Be as descriptive in your question as possible, considering the question background. Every omitted word is usually figurally expensively paid by extra clarification chain.

Comment: Perhaps use the highest volatile petroleum ether fraction and avoid heating. For small vials it should go away easily. Consider that the amount giving deep color to your extracts might be minuscule, so no reason to expect iodine grains as residue.

Comment: Indeed in this protocol the extract is just let aside. https://edu.rsc.org/experiments/extracting-iodine-from-seaweed/1915.article. You should have find it, btw.